# Copying data from proto message into another

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoreflect

I am writing a method which takes a big proto message and copies the information into another proto message(of same type), by reducing the size of few attributes). Example: Lets say the original proto message had attribute called: PhoneNumbers which is array type with 100 values. Then i want to create return new proto message with PhoneNumbers (which has only first 50 values).

The method takes a map which tells how many values which a result copy should have for each of the attributes.

```
syntax = "proto2";

package main;

option go_package = "temp/src";

message Person {
  optional string name = 1;
  optional int32 age = 2;
  repeated int32 departmentIds = 3;
  repeated Address addresses = 4;
}

message Address{
  optional string address = 1;
  repeated PhoneNumber phoneNumbers = 3;
}

message PhoneNumber {
  optional int32 countryCode = 1;
  optional int32 stateCode = 2;
  optional string number = 3;
}


func main() {
        //Create Person instance
    attributeCount := map[string]int{
        "departmentIds": 5,
        "addresses/phoneNumbers":     3,
    }
    newPerson := &Person{}
    stripMessage(person, newPerson, attributeCount)
    fmt.Println(newPerson)
}

func stripMessage(orgMsg proto.Message, newMsg proto.Message, attributeToCount map[string]int) error {
    if len(attributeToCount) == 0 {
        proto.Merge(newMsg, orgMsg)
        return nil
    }

    mds := newMsg.ProtoReflect().Descriptor()
    dm, err := NewDynamicProtoRand(orgMsg, mds, attributeToCount)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    proto.Merge(newMsg, dm)
    return nil
}

func getValue(orgMsg proto.Message, fd protoreflect.FieldDescriptor, attributeCount map[string]int) (protoreflect.Value, error) {
    // process recursively
    rm, err := NewDynamicProtoRand(orgMsg, fd.Message(), attributeCount)
    if err != nil {
        return protoreflect.Value{}, err
    }
    return protoreflect.ValueOfMessage(rm), nil
}

// NewDynamicProtoRand created dynamicpb with assiging random value to proto
func NewDynamicProtoRand(orgMsg proto.Message, mds protoreflect.MessageDescriptor, attributeCount map[string]int) (*dynamicpb.Message, error) {
    dm := dynamicpb.NewMessage(mds)
    fds := mds.Fields()
    for k := 0; k < fds.Len(); k++ {
        fd := fds.Get(k)

        if fd.IsList() {
            list := dm.Mutable(fd).List()
            if fd.Kind() == protoreflect.MessageKind {
                getValue(orgMsg, fd, attributeCount)
            } else {
                values := orgMsg.ProtoReflect().Get(fd).List()
                var lenForAttribute int
                var attributePresent bool
                valuesLen := values.Len()
                for mapKey, mapValue := range attributeCount {
                    if mapKey == fd.TextName() {
                        lenForAttribute = mapValue
                        attributePresent = true
                        break
                    }
                }
                if lenForAttribute > valuesLen {
                    log.Fatalf("Cannot truncate list provided len:%d is greater then lenth:%d", lenForAttribute, valuesLen)
                } else {
                    var requiredValues int
                    if attributePresent {
                        requiredValues = lenForAttribute
                    } else {
                        requiredValues = valuesLen
                    }
                    for l := 0; l < requiredValues; l++ {
                        list.Append(values.Get(l))
                    }
                }
                dm.Set(fd, protoreflect.ValueOfList(list))
                continue
            }
        }

        value := orgMsg.ProtoReflect().Get(fd)

        dm.Set(fd, value)
    }

    return dm, nil
}
```

The above code which works for top level attributes, but fails if a proto is made up of list of another message.
The line: value := orgMsg.ProtoReflect().Get(fd) fails during recursion as orgMsg does not have value for fieldDescriptor of child.
Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: You are trying to dynamize the job with reflection. As a beginner You should avoid using reflection unless you use it for simple cases

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV don't think there is any other way to do it.
Hence i had to go with reflection based solution and it should be generic to handle any type of message type when invoked. Can you tell me if there is any other way possible?

Comment: If you are coming from dynamic languages like javascript, python ... etc you may be willing to do things is dynamic way. But go is a strongly typed language. You have to do many things statically. You may somehow achieve what you want with reflection but that would have negative impact on performance.